# Timer on notification slider for Android

Tags: android, time-management, timer

I'm looking for a Timer for Android that has pause/play button functionality on the notification slider without the need to switch to the Application window itself.

I'm looking specifically for a *countdown* timer.

Price: *Any*

Extra Stuff (Optional but nice to have):

- to be full-feature: ability to create multi-timer, count-up as countdown, as well as lapse.
- Ability to describe the timer: Add title, memo, color.

Comment: Doesn't the default Clock app by Google have this feature? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.deskclock

Answer (score 1):

Try [Brain Focus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.AT.PomodoroTimer&hl=en) - The creator is pretty cool.

It 'has pause/play button functionality on the notification slider without the need to switch to the Application window itself.'